What user does a Docker container run as by default, and is it image dependent?
I am trying to conceptually understand how users work in relation to Docker containers.
A simple way to phrase this question would be

is there any information about which user a Docker Container runs as embedded within a Docker Container Image?


To dig a bit deeper into understanding why I am asking this question, I have written a docker-compose.yaml configuration file to launch a Docker Container with associated Docker Network.
This container fails to run because it cannot obtain RW access to a particular mounted volume.
The folder on the host is has the user and group set to root.
My understanding was that a Docker Container, by default, will run as the root user.
I have not specified any user information in my docker-compose.yaml, and so therefore I assume that docker compose up -d will start the Container, and it will run as the root user.
If information about which user a Docker Container runs as is embedded within a Docker Container Image, then I would be wrong to assume this.
Hence I ask this question.

What user are you talking about? Are you asking about the user inside the container, or about the user on the host?

Dockerfiles have a USER instruction.  https://www.docker.com/blog/understanding-the-docker-user-instruction/

@Turing85 internal container user

The UID of the user in the container is checked for access rights to bind mounted files. As you say, by default a container process runs as UID 0 (root), so it should have access. If you use Windows and WSL2, there are some caveats I believe.

For well-designed image, you can specify the user ID the container uses at runtime, with a docker run -u or Compose user: option.  If the image needs storage on the host specifically it's common to set that to the numeric uid of the host user.

@HansKilian Yes, in this case I am using WSL2

@DavidMaze I'm going to make a bit of a leap here and guess that if a Dockerfile specifies a username, and the expectation is that when a Container created from that Docker Image is run, that it will be run using -u SAME_USERNAME. In other words, when setting the username when building the image, it is expected that someone will use that same username when running the container? Am I along the right lines here?

... and if a Dockerfile does not specify a username, then the default username will be root with uid 0?

The base image you use can also set the user. But if the base image doesn't and you don't, then it runs with uid 0. You can check if there is a USER statement in an image by running the command docker history <image>.

The (last) Dockerfile USER is the default value for the docker run -u option.

I found the answer to my question while looking at the specifications for some Dockerfile for Jenkins.
Some Dockerfile does have a specification for a user id.
Example:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/debian/bookworm/hotspot/Dockerfile

In this example, user id 1000 is used to run the container.
That seems odd to me. Can this id be guaranteed to exist? There is no way to know who is user id 1000, as far as I know...

The numeric user ID isn't guaranteed to be listed in /etc/passwd, but that's not required.  For permission checks it only matters that the numeric uid on disk matches the current effective numeric uid.

@DavidMaze can you explain in more detail? "Current effective numeric uid" - of what?

A process has a user ID, and system calls like geteuid(2) can retrieve it.  That user ID is just a number, maybe 1000 on a typical desktop Linux system, but it could be anything.  Files on disk are also owned by a numeric user, and if those numeric user IDs match, then the (usually more permissive) "owner" file permissions apply.  The user IDs could be mapped to names in /etc/passwd but this isn't strictly required.

@DavidMaze Right, now I understand your comment. Let me bring a new idea in at this point. If a Docker container ran with uid=4444, for example, and this user id did not exist on the Docker Host, then nothing much interesting seems to happen. However, if after running the container, we create a user on the Docker Host using uid=4444, then suddenly something interesting does happen because this user has the same permissions as the Docker Container user.
